# A single word that could replace "You made me blush" sentence

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider a person, A, did a kind gesture for another person, B.
Person B wanted to tell me how did that action make him feel.

The feeling is somehow around the meaning of "He made me blush".

Let's assume that I was offering someone a ride and I do that occasionally, and another person offered him a ride also, which is unexpected. He wanted to tell me that he's sorry while explaining his reasoning/feelings.

> I am sorry, Paul. I will be taking a ride with X, he made me feel [insert word here].

or

> I am sorry, Paul. X [insert word here] me, I am taking a ride with him today.

I thought about the word "embarassed" me, but this doesn't feel like it fits within the context I am looking for.

Comment: The word you use will depend on the emotion/reaction it evokes. It could be anywhere from feeling embarrassed to feeling flattered.

Comment: In my case it's more about feeling flattered to the point where you can't refuse the offer(what ever it was)

Comment: I don't really understand this question, but I wonder if what you're trying to say is something like *X **pressurised** me into accepting a lift with him* - in which context I have no idea what the *grounds* for his insistence (morality-based? threat-based?) might be. I certainly don't think there would be a single verb for the entire action, identifying both the action (forceful persuasion), ***and*** the result (acquiescence) in such a situation..

Comment: Does the single word you are looking for need to fit into both your sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a whole lot of factors. Maybe,

"I wanted to refuse but he shamed me into accepting" (This seems unlikely. Why would someone be ashamed to refuse?)

or

"**He invited me and I was too embarrassed to refuse.**" (This is much more likely).

Answer (score 0):

Flushed might work there.

flush1
[fluhsh]
noun
a blush; rosy glow:
a flush of embarrassment on his face.
a rushing or overspreading flow, as of water.
a sudden rise of emotion or excitement:

dictionary.com

Answer (score -1):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary: 
Elated (adjective) - in high spirits.
According to  CollinsCobuild: 
If you are elated, you are extremely happy and excited because of something that has happened.